# Consuming SalesForce REST API in VisualForce page

Tags: rest, salesforce

I would like to consume SalesForce API using JavaScript that running in VF page that already authenticated. Is it possible to do that without another authentication just to get the security token to call REST API?
What would be the alternative to call SalesForce REST service in valid VF page using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Visualforce Remote Objects](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_vf_remote_objects.htm). It is only in developer preview at the moment but will provide JavaScript proxy objects for DML operations.

Alternatively, you might be better served by [JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) or exposing apex web services that you call from your Javascript.